# c# Custom connecting to a service (metro app)

Tags: c#, facebook

Currently I'm using the standard Connecting to a service (facebook) to authenticate.

[image: Connecting to facebook service]

**But is it possible to make this custom?? (read: make it less ugly)**

[image: Custom faceook service]

Comment: Where is your sample from? You're not *supposed* to request the user's credentials directly. So, by doing so you'll run the risk of violating Facebook's TOS.

Comment: The sample is just a photoshop version. In the application I use the facebook API to get the userName, nothing else.