# WinRT/Windows 8 app - "Connecting to a service" control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8-mail-app

Is there a specific control for the "Connecting to a service" window? Or is it a flyout-type control (or something else) with an embedded WebView?

Thanks.

[Example 1](http://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=2394286f-e26d-4ceb-82f4-3cfd66b5b9a2), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281274/c-sharp-custom-connecting-to-a-service-metro-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) used to connect to oAuth providers. It hosts an internal WebView and manages the callbacks to support single-sign-on via your identity provider.

See [Authentication and user identity (C#/C++/VB)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh750301.aspx) and the [Web authentication broker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122) for details.